# rows to columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas, row, transpose

List item

Any ideas how to go from df

```
id |feature   count
A  |apples      2
A  |oranges     5
A  |pears       9
A  |mandarines  12
```

to this df format?

```
   apples oranges pears mandarines
A    2     5      9      12
```

Tried .T() but no luck

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.set_index('feature', append=True).unstack()['count']
```

Output:

```
feature  apples  mandarines  oranges  pears
A             2          12        5      9
```

Comment: Scott, thank you, it got me closer to the answer. I appreciate your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

you can pivot the dataframe and rename the index column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
    'feature': ['apples', 'oranges', 'pears', 'mandarines'],
    'count': [2, 5, 9, 12]
})

wide_df = df.pivot(index='id', columns='feature', values='count').reset_index()
wide_df.index.name = None
print(wide_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `id` is the index its just a pivot.

```
df.pivot(columns='feature', values='count')

feature  apples  mandarines  oranges  pears
id                                         
A             2          12        5      9
```

Comment: SomeDude, thank you for the suggestion. All these suggestions. Phoenix I think comes closest to what I was looking for but I will test all these suggestions to see which is the best option. Thank you for your help!!!